# How to append a dom element inside another dom element but in first position in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have this html:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div class="inner">Inner</div>
     <div class="inner">Inner</div>
     <div class="inner">Inner</div>
</div>
```

I want to append this line

```
<div id="first">first</div>
```

between the `div#wrapper` and the **first** `div.inner` - so it will always be the first element even if there are no elements.

so it will look like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="first">first</div>
     <div class="inner">Inner</div>
     <div class="inner">Inner</div>
     <div class="inner">Inner</div>
</div>
```

or in case I have no `.inner` div's it will look like this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
     <div id="first">first</div>
</div>
```

How do I do that?
thanks,
Alon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `prepend()` ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/))

```
$('#wrapper').prepend('<div id="first">first</div>');
```