# Insert a tr and td inside a thead

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I currently have a cshtml/javascript/jQuery webapp and I want to insert a `<td>`  inside a `<tr>` inside an existing `<thead>` of a `<table>`. I don't know how can I insert `<tr>` inside an existing `<thead>`. I know how to create one and fill it, but how can I insert new lines?

I want to insert:

```
<tr class="ligne" style="height: 0px; background-color: white;">
    <td style="border-bottom: black 1px solid; padding-bottom: 0px; height: 1px; padding-top: 0px;" colSpan="6"/>
</tr>
```

I want to insert it just under the selected line, below:

[image]

How can I achieve that?

Comment: You might find [jQuery's append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) helpful.

Comment: More generally, see jQuery's methods for [DOM Insertion Inside](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append a dom element inside another dom element but in first position in jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9991637/how-to-append-a-dom-element-inside-another-dom-element-but-in-first-position-in)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an element to a container, after the children of this container, use jQuery method [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

But if you want this element to be the first child of the container, use jQuery method [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/) .

In your case, i would do :

```
$("#GrilleBilan .t-grid-header").prepend("<tr><td> ... </td></tr>")
```

Comment: Good eyes -- `prepend()` *is* more applicable than `append()` in the OP's context.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<thead id='insert_tr'>
</thead>
```

This is your thead and you can insert tr and td both inside thead like this:

```
var appendtr = "";
appendtr += "<tr><th></th></tr>";//And last append this variable inside thead:
 $("#insert_tr").append(appendtr);
```

you can also insert a multiple tr and td and th with tha help of for loop

```
for(var tr = 1; tr <= 5; tr++)
(
 appendtr += "<tr><th></th></tr>";
  $("#insert_tr").append(appendtr);
)
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to insert `<tr><td></td></tr>` after thead used the below code,

```
$('#GrilleBilan .t-grid-header').after('Your element to insert')
```

I am using table id (#GrilleBilan) because if you have more than one table, it did not replcated it other tables to.

Sorry, I missed that

Comment: I think the OP wants to insert the content *inside* the `<thead>`, rather than *after* it.

Comment: Would that work proprely ? 

    $(#GrilleBilan .t-grid-header).after('<tr class="ligne"style="height:0px; background-color: white;"><td style="border-bottom:black 1px solid; padding-bottom: 0px; height: 1px; padding-top:0px;" colSpan="6"/></tr>')

Comment: becuase he want to insert the element after the thead thats why I used after @showdev

Comment: @NalinAggarwal You may be right, but the original post says, "I want to insert a td, inside a tr inside an existing thead..."

Comment: @NalinAggarwal Nothing personal. Your post doesn't seem to be useful in answering the question. You can always edit it though...